# Disable SQL Cache temporary in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, caching, rails-activerecord

I'm currently creating a Rails app with some cronjobs etc, but I have some problems because the sql is cached by Rails.

So anyone know how to disable the SQL Cache in Rails? Not globally, but for this code. Really don't want to create one method for every model, so is there anyway to just disable it temporary?

Terw

Comment: What is the problem caused by the cache?

Comment: Couldn't really determine what was the problem, but solved it with `model.connection.clear_query_cache`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Solved with `model.connection.clear_query_cache`

Answer (score 36):

Another approach is using [ActiveRecord::QueryCache::ClassMethods#uncached](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActiveRecord%2FQueryCache%2FClassMethods%3Auncached)

```
Model.uncached do
  # your code
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was what I was looking for and I was pretty sure there is something like this. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

What specifically worked for me was:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.clear_query_cache
```

With credit for good explanations going to [this blog post](http://intosimple.blogspot.com/2013/03/bypassing-activerecord-cache.html).

Comment: OP specifies "not globally," but +1ed because I found the answer useful nonetheless.