# has_and_belongs_to_many not accessible from both sides of the relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have two models here, courses and studyunits, where a studyunit has content for a course.

Here are the two models:

```
class Studyunit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :studyunits
```

The issue is that adding studyunits to courses seems to update the course. studyunits attribute, but not studyunit.courses. Excerpt of the rspec code:

```
before(:each) do
  course.studyunits << studyunit
  Studyunit.connection.clear_query_cache
 end

it "should be associated with a course" do
  course.studyunits.first.should_not eql(nil)
  studyunit.courses.first.should_not eql(nil)
end
```

The first condition passes, the second fails. How to solve this? I need to access both sides in my code. I tried clearing the query cache as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197135/has-and-belongs-to-many-relationship-not-associating-both-ways), but it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this doesn't just have to do with caching?  I suspect it does.  Try this code instead:

```
it "should be associated with a course" do
  course.studyunits(true).first.should_not eql(nil)
  studyunit.courses(true).first.should_not eql(nil)
end
```

Comment: Ok, that fixed it. That parameter (I assume) turns off caching? I just called it in my code in another trouble spot and it worked perfectly.

Comment: It just tells activerecord to not use the cached version of the relation.  With no value supplied it will use the cached version if available.