# How can I force the rails SQL cache to clear?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I am running `rails db:reset db:migrate` in between tests from within my testing script (which imports and interfaces with the model directly), but the changes are not reflected between the first test and the second test. More specifically, the changes caused by the first test are not reversed as they should be.

When I connect to the database externally (from the shell), I observe that the command has taken effect.

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599875/disable-sql-cache-temporary-in-rails) but the solution had no effect (quite literally, there was no error but also no discernible effect).

How can I force my test script to clear its in-memory cache of the sqlite state?

---

#### Full steps for reproducing the problem.

1. Create a new rails app.

   ```
   rails new MWE
   ```
2. Put the following in `db/schema.rb`

   ```
   ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140408213603) do
       create_table "users", force: true do |t|
       t.string   "username"
     end
   end
   ```
3. Put the following in `db/seed.rb`.

   ```
   User.create(username: 'user1')
   User.create(username: 'user2')
   User.create(username: 'user3')
   ```
4. Put the following in the `Gemfile`.

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org' 
   gem 'rails', '4.0.0' 
   gem 'sqlite3' 
   gem 'protected_attributes'
   ```
5. Put the following in a file called `app/models/user.rb`.

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :username
   end
   ```
6. Run the following commands.

   ```
   bundle install
   rake db:reset
   ```
7. Place the following contents in a file called `MWE.rb`

   ```
   load 'config/application.rb'
   load 'config/environment.rb'
   load 'app/models/user.rb'

   # Mimic the unsafe call in the source code
   system("bundle exec rake db:reset")
   puts User.count
   User.destroy_all("username = 'user3'")
   puts User.count
   system("bundle exec rake db:reset")
   puts User.count
   User.destroy_all("username = 'user3'")
   puts User.count
   ```
8. Run the file and observe **actual output**.

   ```
   $ ruby MWE.rb
   -- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
      -> 0.0362s
   -- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
      -> 0.0248s
   3
   2
   -- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
      -> 0.0809s
   -- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
      -> 0.0490s
   2
   2
   ```

#### Desired Output

```
    -- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
       -> 0.0362s
    -- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
       -> 0.0248s
    3
    2
    -- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
       -> 0.0809s
    -- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
       -> 0.0490s
    3
    2
```

**How can I force the DB reset to be reflected in the model?**

Comment: Could you post some code so we could reproduce the issue?

Comment: @BroiSatse, I'm working on it. It is non-trivial to create an MWE for this, so I figured I'd post before I finished the MWE in case anyone had already seen this problem.

Comment: @BroiSatse, Full MWE posted. Note that I am a relative novice in ruby / rails, so if you know of a way to make this MWE even smaller, please also comment on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to reestablish database connection. Try:

```
system("bundle exec rake db:reset")
puts User.count
User.destroy_all("username = 'user3'")
puts User.count

system("bundle exec rake db:reset")
ActiveRecord::Base.clear_all_connections!
puts User.count
User.destroy_all("username = 'user3'")
puts User.count
```

The main question is: why do you need to do this? I am pretty certain there is a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I am writing an autograder for a class that I am teaching. One of the assignments to be graded is a SQL Injection and since there are many ways such an injection can be written incorrectly, I want to reset the state of my database between running different students' submissions.

Comment: @merlin2011 - That sounds pretty cool. :) So they will write some code on the website and you want to run it as a migration?

Comment: Yeah, that's the general idea. Unfortunately, certain parts of the project depend on Ruby, and Ruby is not exactly my mother tongue. :P

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still getting `undefined method `clear_all_connections!'` even with `gem activerecord` in the Gemfile.

Comment: No worries, happy to help. Enjoy the grader. :)