# Why would Postgres clock_timestamp freeze inside a Rails unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a system inside of a Rails application where I make multiple SQL queries which need a proper system clock to work (at least inside of Postgres). I am seeing that while in the Rails console the timestamp functions in Postgres work correctly, when I run the same SQL inside of my unit tests the clock gets frozen - so `clock_timestamp()` which is supposed to be a representation of the system clock - lives its own separate life. Which is obviously very confusing, as I do *not* want my time frozen in this way. I know that Postgres has the transaction start timestamps, which would be frozen in this way inside of a ("transactional") Rails test, but I am not using them - *on purpose* - I am using `clock_timestamp()` which is supposed to be exempt from this. For example, running this inside the Rails console:

```rb
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
10.times do
  sleep(0.3)
  sys_t, conn_t = Time.now.utc, conn.select_value("SELECT clock_timestamp()")
  drift = sys_t - conn_t
  warn "Drift between clocks: #{drift}"
end
```

gives me the following:

```
Drift between clocks: -0.002037
Drift between clocks: -0.001479
Drift between clocks: -0.001332
Drift between clocks: -0.001402
Drift between clocks: -0.000776
Drift between clocks: -0.001721
Drift between clocks: -0.001453
Drift between clocks: -0.001522
Drift between clocks: -0.000768
Drift between clocks: -0.001513
```

However, the same code inside a unit test gives me this:

```
# Running tests with run options --seed 15342:

Drift between clocks: -0.000866
Drift between clocks: 0.301889
Drift between clocks: 0.604441
Drift between clocks: 0.912252
Drift between clocks: 1.215088
Drift between clocks: 1.517945
Drift between clocks: 1.820126
Drift between clocks: 2.125937
Drift between clocks: 2.428927
Drift between clocks: 2.731635
```

which is very perplexing.

For reference, this can be reproduced on a blank slate Rails application with a test like this:

```rb
require "test_helper"

class BleghTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_drift
    conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    10.times do
      sleep(0.3)
      sys_t, conn_t = Time.now.utc, conn.select_value("SELECT clock_timestamp()")
      drift = sys_t - conn_t
      warn "Drift between clocks: #{drift}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So you have proven there is something wrong with your unit test. Show the rest of the code for the unit test and the test setup.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my particular unit test - the above is reproducible on a blank Rails application with stock gems, where the only test contains exclusively the code I posted. But sure, I will paste in the test.

Comment: Maybe Rails caches the SQL requests during the test, as it does for HTTP requests. Try to add `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.clear_query_cache` in the loop.

Comment: @Baldrick ActiveRecord has built in SQL caching but it mostly works when dealing with ActiveRecord::Relation instances. Not completely sure that it would apply when doing "raw" queries with the connection handler but you could try `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.clear_query_cache` or any of the tricks listed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599875/disable-sql-cache-temporary-in-rails

Comment: Indeed - I fell victim to Rails query caching, which in this case has to be surrounded by `uncached {}` to suppress. If one of you folks wants to post an answer I will accept